# Can I link to my own previous question if I think it may add some context?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, linked-questions

I have asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672036/what-is-causing-a-fatal-error-when-sending-email-from-a-contact-form-via-php-and) based off of another question I received an answer for that I accepted.

Rather than copy all of my code and wording across two different questions and run the risk of it appearing as a duplicate, I added all of the relevant information, and then linked the original question towards the end so that some context could be given to the current question if required - almost as an appendix.

I believe that my current question can be read as self-contained, and I don't believe that the linked question witholds any information that I didn't put into my current question, however I did deem it necessary to provide almost a backstory to my current problem so that potential answers can be fully informed as to how I got to my current state.

Is this acceptable?  If not, is there any scope for providing context while still offering a self-contained question?

Comment: Yes, sure. Why not?

Comment: As long as the new question stands on its own you're fine.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The way you approached it looks like the right choice to me. If you have a new question about the same code, that code should appear in the new question so that it stands on its own. There's nothing wrong with providing the link for context, but people shouldn't be forced to follow a link (even to another question on Stack Overflow) to get all the information they need to provide an answer.

Comment: This is what I'm getting at - I think it's self contained, and I can take the link out with no loss of information, but sometimes I feel you need to provide 'appendices' as it were to give the entire story.

Comment: @tomdot I think you struck the right balance. You want to include all the information necessary, but you don't want to overwhelm people with any information that might not be *absolutely* necessary. Copying some information and linking to the rest does just that.

Comment: Sometimes [a link to something you wrote is all you need](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300371/can-i-link-to-my-own-previous-question-if-i-think-it-may-add-some-context?cb=1#comment226808_300373).

Comment: @philipxy True Meta SO!

Comment: @philipxy Sitting since 5 minutes on your comment. And every link takes me to another. You should not force me to follow ;)

Comment: @Christian, it's a trap!